# Tesseract api linker (or build?) problem on window

Tags: c++, compilation, tesseract, linker-errors

I want to use tesseract api on my project. And the problem is I can't compile my test code that look like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>   

int main()
{
   tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
   api->End();
   delete api;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using this

```
g++ -L/Projects/cpp/CPE1/Project/lib/ -ltesseract50 -lleptonica -I/Projects/cpp/CPE1/Project/include t.cpp -o t
```

and got

```
C:\Users\MSINOT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4xWMfF.o:t.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()'
C:\Users\MSINOT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4xWMfF.o:t.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::End()'   
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my folder structure looks like this (this is all on drive D:)

```
\---Project
    +---bin
    +---cmake
    +---include
    |   +---leptonica
    |   \---tesseract
    +---leptonica-1.80.0
    +---lib
    |   +---cmake
    |   \---pkgconfig
    +---tesseract-master
    \---Uics
        [my code is here]
```

I compiled leptonica and tesseract following this https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#windows on "Develop Tesseract" and specify install path to my project folder.

I'm a noob in this type of problem, so if you have completely different ways to use tesseract API pls tell me.

> g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
>
> Tesseract from main branch https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
>
> Leptonica from 1.80.0 release
> https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica
>
> cmake version 3.19.4

*edit add lib folder listing

```
D:\PROJECTS\CPP\CPE1\PROJECT\LIB
|   leptonica.lib
|   tesseract50.lib
|
+---cmake
|   +---leptonica
|   |       LeptonicaConfig-version.cmake
|   |       LeptonicaConfig.cmake
|   |       LeptonicaTargets-release.cmake
|   |       LeptonicaTargets.cmake
|   |
|   \---tesseract
|           TesseractConfig.cmake
|           TesseractConfigVersion.cmake
|           TesseractTargets-release.cmake
|           TesseractTargets.cmake
|
\---pkgconfig
        lept.pc
        tesseract.pc
```

Comment: I think ordering of link arguments:  Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603575/why-does-the-order-of-passing-parameters-to-g-matter

Comment: sadly it doesn't work. got the same errors.

Comment: Can you provide listing of "/Projects/cpp/CPE1/Project/lib/" directory?

Comment: @user898678 I edit the questions for you, Is the problem in this folder?

Comment: I do not use g++ on windows, but tesseract50.lib looks like VSC++ library and not g++ library.